# Validate input with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something like this code below but have so far not being successful.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;
    return true;
} // restrict numerical values only
```

The code above only allows for numerical characters, and when a user push any other key apart from the Numerical ones, it does not appear on the text box.

This is exactly what I want too but the scenario is different, I don't want the user to enter zero (0) as their first character.

e.g. 0909 wrong but instead 909

I have being able to achieve this thus far

```
$(".input-xlarge").keyup(function () {
    var textInField = this.value;

    if (textInField.length == 1) {
        if (textInField == 0) {
            showError('error?');
        }
    }
});
```

but instead a message should be shown to the user, the input should be ignored just like the first code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the fiddle, this "blocks" the text box for only valid input via js.

HTML:

```
<input id='numeric' type='text'/>
```

JS:

```
$('#numeric').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8) // allow backspace - add more chars here
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57 || (e.keyCode == 48 && $(this).val() == '')) // non numeric + beginning zero
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ7La/)

Comment: The KeyDown event is triggered when the user presses a Key.
The KeyUp event is triggered when the user releases a Key.

Answer (score 1):

This would work,

```
$(".input-xlarge").keyup(function (evt) {
    var textInField = this.value;
    if (textInField.length == 1) {
        if (textInField == 0) {
            alert('number should not start with zero');
            $(evt.target).val("")
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: To improve your answer, you could explain why this would work.

Comment: this works but the zero (0) appears before being deleted automatically. I needed it not to appear on the textbox at all.

Comment: Then just remove the alert, It will delete zero as soon as key is up

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(".input-xlarge").keyup(function (event) {
    var textInField = this.value;

    if (textInField.substr(0, 1) == '0') {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("should not start with zero');
    }
});
```

By doing this, whenever your user input `0` as the first letter, then it won't be showed and will alert an error message.

Comment: Ah, don't use keyup, instead use keydown.. because during keyup event your character already input into the field..

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".input-xlarge" ).keyup(function(e) {
  var textInField = this.value; 
  if (textInField.length == 1){
    if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 ){
      alert('cannot start with zero')
      return false;
   }
  }
});
```

refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4L6t/1/)